# How to apply conditional formatting over multiple ranges

Tags: excel, formatting, format, conditional-statements, range

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a range A2:J2150, but each row depends on the value in column K. So A2:J2 will depend on the value in cell K2 and the range of A20:J20 will depend of the value in cell K20. I can apply the range to one row, but is there a way to copy over that specific conditional formatting to the rest of the range? Or is there a formula to apply my requirements over the ranges?

Comment: You would change the applies to: to `$A$2:$J$2150` and use the formula that refers to `$K2` as your condition.  Excel will iterate the row appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I think I had this on another worksheet a couple years ago and forgot how I solved it. I just didn't have the time this time to play with around with conditional formatting.